# How to rate movies on AppleTV

Tags: appletv

I just rented a movie on Apple TV.  How do I give it a star rating, i.e 1-5 stars?

When you select a movie on Apple TV, it shows a rotten tomatoes rating and a star rating. In the past I stumbled across the star rating selector UI by accident- now I can't find it.

I have a third-gen Apple TV running 6.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (March 2017) you have to login to iTunes to rate and leave a review. I hope they add this feature to Apple TV soon.

Answer (score 1):

I just watched Gladiator for probably the 5th time and, with a tear in my eye, wanted to give it a 5 star rating. I have rated movies in the past on Apple TV but cannot find how to do it anymore. I can't find it on the rental screen, the "more" menu, or the menu while the movie is playing. I've also looked to see if it is only available to purchased movies which is not the case. I am left to believe the feature has been removed. I hope I am wrong.

However, I also scoured the internet for an image of someone rating a movie on Apple TV and could not find one, which leads me to believe I am crazy. Maybe were both crazy. Or maybe it's just gone because no one cared about it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In iTunes, rented tab, graphic of movie rented, right click on the picture, select Love or Dislike. Also an option to go to movie in iTunes store. Click on that link and you can choose how many stars and even write a review. SOLVED.